# fork() inside a function only on the first call to the function

Tags: c, linux

I have a function , say pfoo() and I would like to create a child process inside it by calling fork. This function is called many times repeatedly but I would like the child process to be created only the first time the function is called.

Is it possible to achieve this?
How should I change the function below to ensure fork() is called only the first time? Do I need to cache cpid?

```
void pfoo()
{
    pid_t cpid = fork();
    if ( cpid == 0 )
    {
        // child process
    }
    else
    {
        // parent process
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: `static int forked = 0; if (!forked) { ... }`

Comment: `static pid_t cpid = 0; if (cpid == 0) { ... }`

Comment: @ikegami - I thought of that, but what if the OP wanted to stop it forking in the child process as well?

Comment: This sounds like a dubious design — the function does two different jobs.  It isn't functionally cohesive.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, nah. Imagine an implementation of `fact(n)` that offloads the work to a child process, and reuses the child process if there are multiple calls to `fact(n)`. The caller doesn't care about that; they just want `fact(n)`. [Of course, the fact that you are creating a child process is probably not something you want to keep secret, but that's not relevant to your comment.]

Comment: @ikegami if you need an offloading implementation of `sin(x)` later, should you repeat all this process handling code you already have in `fact(n)`, or should you reuse it? You need sin(x)` and `fact(n)` to be in two different processes.

Comment: @n.m., Noone suggested you can't use reusable functions to create the worker. Feel free to do `if (pid == 0) create_worker(&pid, &request_pipe_fd, &response_pipe_fd, ...);`

Answer (score 2):

`static` variables keep their value from call to call.

```
int calc(int n) {
    static pid_t pid = 0;
    static int request_pipe_fd;
    static int response_pipe_fd;

    if (pid == 0) {
        ... create the worker ... 
    }

    ...
}
```

You can also use file-scoped varaiables.

```
static pid_t calc_worker_pid = 0;
static int calc_worker_request_pipe_fd;
static int calc_worker_response_pipe_fd;

void launch_calc_worker() {
    if (calc_worker_pid != 0)
        return;

    ... create the worker ... 
}

void terminate_calc_worker() {
    if (calc_worker_pid == 0)
        return;

   ... terminate and reap the worker ...

   calc_worker_pid = 0;
}

int calc(int n) {
    launch_calc_worker();

    ...
}
```